# Multi-conditional lookup (conditions both in rows and columns) using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am a teacher. Let's say -

I have **3 students**. Their IDs are: *100,125, and 116*.

I take classes in **3 consecutive periods**. *Period 1, 2 and 3*.

I take classes 5 days a week. 40 minutes per class.

I keep records of their attendance in an excel sheet named **DATAsheet**. The sheet looks like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | STUDENT ID | DATE | PERIOD | MINUTES ATTENDED IN CLASS |
| 2 | studentID100 | 9/1/2020 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | studentID125 | 9/1/2020 | 1 | 39 |
| 4 | studentID116 | 9/1/2020 | 1 | 26 |
| 5 | studentID125 | 9/1/2020 | 2 | 16 |
| 6 | studentID116 | 9/1/2020 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | studentID100 | 9/1/2020 | 3 | 22 |
| 8 | studentID116 | 9/1/2020 | 3 | 16 |
| 9 | studentID100 | 9/2/2020 | 1 | 9 |
| 10 | studentID116 | 9/2/2020 | 1 | 24 |
| 11 | studentID125 | 9/2/2020 | 1 | 35 |
| 12 | studentID125 | 9/2/2020 | 2 | 17 |
| 13 | studentID116 | 9/2/2020 | 2 | 13 |
| 14 | studentID100 | 9/2/2020 | 2 | 36 |
| 15 | studentID125 | 9/2/2020 | 3 | 13 |
| 16 | studentID116 | 9/2/2020 | 3 | 1 |

Please note: in this sheet, student IDs don't follow any fixed order.

I want to convert this into a different table in a separate sheet called **OUTPUTsheet**. The data should look like this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 9/1/2020 | 9/1/2020 | 9/1/2020 | 9/2/2020 | 9/2/2020 | 9/2/2020 |
| 2 |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | studentID100 | 4 | NA | 22 | 9 | 36 | NA |
| 4 | studentID125 | 39 | 16 | NA | 35 | 17 | 13 |
| 5 | studentID116 | 26 | 2 | 16 | 24 | 13 | 1 |

Here, student IDs are in column A. Dates are in row 1. Periods are in row 2. And rest of the data is duration (in minutes) each student attended class each period.
**Column A, Row 1 and Row 2 in OUTPUTsheet are pre-set manually**.

The VBA code I used:

```
    Sub student_attendance_sheet()

    
    Dim Found As Range, Firstfound As String
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim Criteria1 As Variant, Criteria2 As Variant
    
    Set rngSearch = Sheets("DATAsheet").Range("A:A")
    
    
    For i = 3 To 5
        For j = 2 To 7
    
            With Sheets("OUTPUTsheet")
            Criteria1 = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            Criteria2 = .Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(2, j)).Value
            End With
                
            Set Found = rngSearch.Find(What:=Criteria1, _
                                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                       MatchCase:=False)
                
            If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                
                Firstfound = Found.Address
            
                Do
                    If Found.EntireRow.Range("B1").Value = Criteria2(1, 1) And _
                       Found.EntireRow.Range("C1").Value = Criteria2(2, 1) Then Exit Do 'Match found
                    
                    Set Found = rngSearch.FindNext(After:=Found)
                    If Found.Address = Firstfound Then Set Found = Nothing
                    
                Loop Until Found Is Nothing
                
            End If
            
            If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                
        
                Sheets("OUTPUTsheet").Cells(i, j).Value = Found.Offset(, 3)
                
            Else
        
                Sheets("OUTPUTsheet").Cells(i, j).Value = ""
            End If
    
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

The code works. But **veeery slow**. Plus, This code **does not handles errors well**. For example, there was a `#N/A` in C15 in DATAsheet, which gave an error "Type Mismatch".

**My real data consists of 20,000 columns and 2,000 rows.** Even a formula approach or pivot table approach would be way faster than this. For some reason, I want to use VBA. But I want it to be faster than the other two approaches.

**Can you suggest any improvement to this code or any other alternative code which performs faster and handles errors?** Maybe using arrays or something like that.

Comment: Why not pivot table then? If you want it in VBA only then also, Pivot table is a good option

Comment: Any excel or vba solution will be slow. Other data handling programs exist and will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub student_attendance_sheet()

    Const INPUT_SHT = "DATAsheet"
    Const OUTPUT_SHT = "OUTPUTsheet"

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iLastCol As Integer, r As Long, c As Integer
    Dim dictCol As Object, dictRow As Object, key As String, sId As String
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    Dim cel as range

    Set dictCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictRow = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsIn = wb.Sheets(INPUT_SHT)
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHT)

    ' profile output sheet
    iLastCol = wsOut.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    For c = 2 To iLastCol
       key = Format(wsOut.Cells(1, c), "YYYYMMDD") & Format(wsOut.Cells(2, c), "00")
       dictCol.Add key, c
    Next

    ' students
    iLastRow = wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 3 To iLastRow
        key = Trim(wsOut.Cells(r, "A"))
        dictRow.Add key, r
    Next

    ' clear output sheet
    wsOut.Range("B3").Resize(iLastRow - 2, iLastCol - 1).ClearContents

    ' scan input
    iLastRow = wsIn.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To iLastRow

        sId = Trim(wsIn.Cells(r, "A"))
        key = Format(wsIn.Cells(r, "B"), "YYYYMMDD") & Format(wsIn.Cells(r, "C"), "00")

        If Not dictRow.exists(sId) Then
            'MsgBox "ERROR - No output row for " & sId, vbCritical
            'Exit Sub
        ElseIf Not dictCol.exists(key) Then
            MsgBox "ERROR - No output col for " & key, vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        Else

            ' update mins
            Set cel = wsOut.Cells(dictRow(sId), dictCol(key))
            cel.Value = cel.Value + wsIn.Cells(r, "D")
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox iLastRow - 1 & " rows scanned in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs"), vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: if a studentID has multiple entries in a period, for example, if row 2 in the DATAsheet here is duplicated, I want to add the minutes to 8 (4+4) in that period. How can I modify your wonderful code?

Comment: Perfect! One more thing, if a studentID is missing in the OUTPUTsheet, an error message pops up "ERROR - No output row for ". What if I want to keep only selected studentIDs in the OUTPUTsheet? What changes should I make in the code? Should I delete the IF statement?

Comment: Superb! Just noticed one thing- when I run this code once, it's fine. But when I run It again, original value is multiplied every time.

Comment: @Imran Clear the output sheet with `wsOut.Range("B3").Resize(iLastRow - 2, iLastCol - 1).ClearContents` before  scan input - see update

Comment: Thanks a lot! Initially I tried `cel.ClearContents` in the 2nd line in update mins. As a beginner with VBA, I am so impressed with your code that I researched a lot on dictionary method. It's amazing! Thanks again to all the mentors like you to show me new avenues of learning.